# What is the Krull dimension of the Burnside ring of $\mathbb N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, monoid, krull-dimension, functors

A contravariant functor $F$ from monoids to commutative rings was defined [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3153930/660).

> **Question.** What is the Krull dimension of $F(\mathbb N)$?

(Here $\mathbb N$ denotes the *additive* monoid $(\mathbb N,+)$.)

(If $G$ is a finite group, then $F(G)$ is the *Burnside ring* of $G$.)

This question is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154240/660) outstanding answer of Eric Wofsey.